# How to find the parent object of an object(Standard and Custom Object) whose sharing settings are controlled by parent through SOQL/RestiAPi?

Tags: sharing, access, org-wide-defaults

For Organization-Wide Defaults Internal Default Access there are objects set as     Controlled by Parent.

Is there an approach which I can follow to find parent of those standard/custom objects either by SOQL or RestApi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Standard Objects, there's no particular attribute that definitively points out which field is the parent for purposes of sharing. You just have to check the documentation in this case if you're unsure. If you need this programmatically, you'll have to make a mapping somehow.

For Custom Objects, the parent is the field that returns 0 for `getRelationshipOrder`, as demonstrated in this short Apex function:

```
public sObjectField getParentField(sObjectType entity) {
    for(sObjectField field: entity.getDescribe().fields.getMap().values()) {
        if(field.getDescribe().getRelationshipOrder() == 0) {
            return field;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In either case, SOQL won't help you here. As far as the REST API is concerned, describe the object and look for the `relationshipOrder` property with the value of `0` (not `null` or `1`).

Comment: This helps a lot. relationshipOrder is what I wanted to confirm. Thank you.

Comment: For custom object, by default there is CustomObjectName(nameField=true) field created which by default has read and edit access in fieldpermissions (On UI Permission Set Page ) . When I query object permission and field permission object for that user through soql I don't see any record which says CustomObjectName field read/write true ? From where are these fields set to true and they are non editable ?

Comment: @KishanPatel Right. Salesforce has certain fields, like Id and Name, that must be visible and must be either required or readonly. You cannot change the behavior of these fields, so they cannot be queried in the SOQL query for FieldPermissions. This is system behavior that cannot be altered; the permissions are set and enforced by the system itself.

Comment: Is there a way I can get such list either from describe object or any soql ? Like I know namefield=true do have fieldpermission set to true, but what about other fields which may have fieldpermission as true which are system driven ?

Comment: @KishanPatel You can iterate through all the fields checking the `isPermissionable()` method (Apex) or from the `permissionable` property (SOAP/REST APIs). If this flag is unset (false), then it is some type of system field that can't have permissions applied.

Comment: What is the SOQL query for obtaining all the objects which are visible on Object Manager screen ?

Comment: @KishanPatel There's no such SOQL; you'd want to use Schema.getGlobalDescribe (Apex), or the Describe Global calls (REST/SOAP), etc. From there, you'd have to describe them and figure out which ones you want to show. There's a Q&A on here somewhere that describes how to detect the difference between Object Manager objects and all objects, I just don't have it on hand at the moment.